# How to reasonably denote lines, line segments and rays?

Tags: secondary-education, geometry, notation

I'm teaching geometry at high school for the first time soon and am struggling to find a reasonable notation for lines, line segments and rays defined by two points $A$, $B$ (and a direction). At the high school I'm teaching at, everyone just uses the notation they're familiar with already, and most of geometry is taught without a textbook.

I've come across rays starting at $A$ being denoted by $\overrightarrow{AB}$, which I'm not a fan of, because many people also use this for vector notation. Some people use $\overline{AB}$ for lines, some for line segments. Those people then use $AB$ for line segments and lines, respectively.

What should I do about this?

Comment: French notation (following Bourbaki): $[AB]$ is the segment including endpoints. $(AB)$ is the line. $[AB)$ is the ray from $A$ to $B$ to infinity. $]AB)$ means $[AB)$ without the point $A$. $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is the line vector. Of course there's also $[AB[$, $]AB]$, $]AB[$ etc. This geometric notation is similar to the real intervals notation $[a,b]$ is the closed bounded interval, $]a,b[$ is the open interval etc. But in some countries, other ambiguous notations are used like $(a,b)$ for the open interval which look exactly like an ordered couple!

Comment: @whatever: Yes, over here, we almost exclusively use $(a,b)$ for open intervals.

Comment: I've added the (secondary-education) tag because of the high school context. If you feel the question is more generally applicable, please feel free to rollback the [edit](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/posts/11300/revisions).

Comment: @Huy In your comment you say "over here" but you haven't said what country you are in.  Since notation is often region-specific that seems like pertinent information.

Comment: Switzerland, which is also listed in my profile. I wasn't aware that this was a region-issue.

Comment: I am surprised that at a Swiss high school teachers do not have a textbook.  I was under the impression that Switzerland had a standardized national mathematics curriculum.

Comment: No, it doesn't at all. Choosing high schools is like choosing majors, so obviously kids who go to a maths-focused high school will learn a bit more maths than those who go to a language-focused high school. The *minimal level* of maths is sort of standardized, as far as I know.

Comment: Does it matter which canton you are in?  I have seen documents referring to the secondary geometry curriculum standards of Luzern, for example.

Comment: Yes, it varies from canton to canton. If you're interested to talk about this, I invite you to come to the MSE chat some time, I'm very frequently around, so feel free to ping me any time. (instead of making this a huge comment chain mostly unrelated to the question)

Comment: See for example Hoyles, Celia and Foxman, Derek and Küchemann, Dietmar and Kuchemann, Dietmar (2002) A comparative study of geometry curricula, which compares the geometry curricula of 9 countries, one of which is Switzerland.

Comment: I use $(a,b)$ for both the open interval and the point with $x$-coordinate $a$ and $y$-coordinate $b$. I cannot remember the last time it caused confusion. It's almost always clear from context what is meant.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Using this notation $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ could mean the cross product of 2 vectors or the cartesian product of 2 sets. Sure, you may say that the student should know which one is implied but why stick to this notation when there's a better alternative (consistent with geometric notation, see my 1st comment). This is similar to the international system (m, kg,...) vs the old system (inch, foot, pound, ...).

Comment: @whatever perhaps, but, this is easily fixed by simply declaring what type of object $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is before making the statement $(a,b) \times (c,d)$.

Answer (score 5):

The most important thing, in my opinion, is to adopt a notation that is consistent with whatever is most common in the broader culture.  Geometry notation is highly context-specific; notation used at the secondary level tends to be different from that used at the undergraduate level, and there are country-to-country differences as well.  If there is any kind of national or regional school-leavers exam (comparable to A-levels in the UK or to the SAT in the United States) you should use whatever notation is standard on that exam.

I don't know much about the Swiss educational system, but I find it frankly hard to believe that there is no standard notation in use in your context.  The Swiss geometry curriculum was one of nine national curricula compared in:

> Hoyles, C., Foxman, D. and Küchemann, D. (2002) *A comparative study of geometry curricula*. Qualifications and Curriculum Authority, London. ISBN 1858385091

...and while I don't have access to that book at the moment the mere fact that it exists suggests to me that there *is* a national geometry curriculum in Switzerland.

If you genuinely do teach in a vacuum, free of external encumbrances and with no cultural norms to align yourself with, then I guess you are free to choose whatever makes sense to you.

In the United States, standard notation at the *secondary* level is:

- $\overline{AB}$ denotes the line segment from $A$ to $B$
- $\overrightarrow{AB}$ denotes the ray with initial point $A$ and passing through $B$ (but note that a conventional Geometry class in the United States typically does not include vectors, so there is no conflict with that notation)
- $AB$ denotes the length of the segment $\overline{AB}$
- $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ denotes the line through $A$ and $B$

At the advanced undergraduate or graduate level, different notations tend to be used; for example, I believe Greenberg's text uses $AB$ to denote a line, rather than the length of a segment, but otherwise uses the conventions above.

Comment: I don't know what qualifies as a "curriculum", but with my interpretation, I can guarantee that there is no such thing as a national, not even cantonal standardized curriculum. As I mentioned in another comment, there are only (sort of) *minimal expectations*. Even within a high school, subjects that are covered can vary greatly. I honestly don't understand why that is hard to believe - the Swiss education works very differently than the US education, and that is just one part of it (not just in maths).

Comment: Oh, the US system is completely decentralized, with no national curriculum at all -- but my understanding was that European educational systems tend to be more centralized.

Comment: This is the same notation that was taught to me in high school in the Philippines.

Comment: How do you simply denote the segment $AB$ without the point $B$? Also $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ ($\overleftrightarrow{~}$ is sometimes used for tensors)  is very similar to $\overrightarrow{AB}$ whereas in reality they are very different.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest not using a notation at all. "line $AB$", "segment $AB$", "ray $AB$" seems OK to me, and it forces you to write your proofs in text rather than using shorthand and over-formalization.